# Implementing a solver in c++ for problems described in some scripting syntax

Tags: c++, dynamic, solver

I have a generic question on how to write a C++ code to solve a general class of problems. The class of problems are described in some scripting language that will be read dynamically by the c++ program. E.g. the problem can be described like the following:

```
syms a b c x
sol = solve(a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0)
sola = solve(a*x^2 + b*x + c == 0, a)
```

Here I am just using MATLAB for illustration purposes, and I am not trying to build anything like MATLAB. What I am really after is to find out how, in general, does one go about designing a C++ program that will take in a script, which describes some calculation instructions, and then read/interpret the logic described in the script and then perform the calculations as described.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has an example in his [Programming Principles and Practice using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/) for how one would go about making a calculator (so that a user could type "4 + 6 =;" and the program would calculate it). There's an [example here](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator00.cpp) which might be a helpful place to start

Comment: I agree with @Tas, you need to find first a text that shows you how to implement the parser. A source (quite old) that I have found useful is Niklaus Wirth Algorithms + Data structures = Programming. As an alternative search for terms as 'Parser expression term factor'

Comment: I'd recommend the [boost spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit) library for parsing such a script and invoking actions to encode the content in whatever variables / data structures you deem necessary. As for "performing the calculation" - once you have the inputs / formulas stored in your data structures of choice, that's a much more focused question that you can find existing answers on. As is, this whole quesion is too unfocused and broad....

Answer (score 0):

The general architecture of your program will look as follows:

[image]

(from the [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) article on Wikipedia)

There are plenty of tutorials covering [lexical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and building parse trees or, more often, abstract syntax trees (AST). See, for example, the [Kaleidoscope tutorial](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/LangImpl2.html) from LLVM.

Once you constructed the AST, you'll need to translate it into some internal representation such as byte code and pass it to an interpreter or a virtual machine. In some cases it is possible to skip this step and work directly with AST.

Interpreter will take the input generated on the previous step, construct the runtime representation of the algebraic problem (which is also a tree-like data structure) and pass it to the actual solver.

The solver will analyze the structure of the problem and apply relevant methods to find the solution for the equation. For example, if `x` is a variable and `a`, `b` and `c` are parameters in your example, it can detect that it is a quadratic equation and apply well known formulas to find the solution.